# Using Javascript in ios

Tags: javascript, ios

This is my ios code

```
webView             =   [[UIWebView alloc] init];
webView.delegate    =   self;

[webView loadHTMLString:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"myFile.js\"></script>" baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSBundle mainBundle].resourcePath]];

NSString* result =(NSString*)[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunction(%d,%d,%d)", num1,num2,num3]];

NSLog(@"RESULT1 : %@", result);
```

And this is myFile.js

```
function myFunction(a,b,c)
{
   return a*b*c;
}
```

I dont get anything in the **result** string. Am i wrong??

Answer (score 0):

After loading webview, you should wait for `webViewDidFinishLoad:` callback which gets called when webview completes loading.

Implement the delegate method like this,

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString* result = (NSString*)[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunction(%d,%d,%d)", num1,num2,num3]];
    NSLog(@"RESULT1 : %@", result);
}
```

Also, check if your `myFile.js` is present under **Copy Bundle Resources** and not under **Compile Sources** section of *Target->Build Phases*.

---

I am not a JS expert but the syntax for your JS function seems odd. Usually the syntax is

```
function myFunction(a,b,c)
{
   //Check if this alert gets called
   alert('Function called');
   return a*b*c;
}
```

Please check.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Shob-Z Did you check if the `baseURL:` parameter is correctly passed? Also is your .js included in resources and not compile sources?

Comment: Sorry.. I typed it wrong here.. But in my code its in the way u told

Comment: @Shob-Z Okay, does `webViewDidFinishLoad:` get called?

Comment: Yes.. it gets called.. But nothing happens.. the result string is still empty.

Comment: @Shob-Z Add `alert('Some msg')` in your JS function `myFunction()`. Check if these alerts are triggered. If they are not called, I suspect the JS file path is incorrect and your script file is not getting loaded.